# how to make ngModel works in angulardart?

Tags: angular-dart

I am new to angulardart.
The template compiler doesn’t recognize ngModel.

Please help!!

I followed the instruction in angulardart website.
I tried to update pubspec.yaml
but I dont understand this:
{toh-0 → toh-1}/pubspec.yaml

@@ -8,2 +8,3 @@
8
8
dependencies:
9
9
angular: ^5.3.0
10
+ angular_forms: ^2.1.2

and here is the instruction link:
https://angulardart.dev/tutorial/toh-pt1

Comment: Is formDirectives added to your directives list? If so it would help if there was more code that you added to your question. This doesn't have enough context to help.

Answer (score 0):

Please update your pubspec.yaml according to

- https://github.com/angular-examples/toh-1/blob/master/pubspec.yaml

Also add/update the following in your component's dart file.

`import 'package:angular_forms/angular_forms.dart';`

`@Component(
  selector: ...,
  directives: [formDirectives],
)`